# Stop python eval() from removing brackets

Tags: python, eval

A string variable is defined `clause1 = "((1 & z[0]) != 0)"`

Its eval() gives `BoolRef: 1 & v__a != 0`
while I actually need `BoolRef: ((1 & v__a) != 0)`

How to keep the brackets in eval() and evaluate everything else

Comment: Have you tried escaping the brackets, i.e. `\[` and `\]`?

Comment: What version of python is this?

Comment: Do you mean replacing `(` and `)` by `\(` and `\)` respectively. I tried this and got error as
`File "<string>", line 1
\(\(1 & z[0]\) != 0\)
                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: I tried these in python 2.7 and it seems to work fine... >>> clause1 = "((1 & z[0]) != 0)"
>>> z =[1, 2, 3]
>>> eval(clause1)

Comment: Its working fine for me too. Its just that I don't want to get rid of brackets because otherwise the expression evaluates to something else

Comment: Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Where did you get the "BoolRef" result from?

Comment: I am using z3 SMT solver and got it from there. I am composing a small example to illustrate my point. Will put it in sometime

Comment: What's the type of `z[0]`?

Comment: Is it builtin `eval()` function or is it from `z3`? Builtin `eval` returns an expression `expr = eval(clause1)`; what you see is probably the result of printing that expression. What `print expr` and `print repr(expr)` produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing `eval()` with the exact type of `z[0]`, which is, I guess, what does the magic here.  I believe that if you try to run `((1 & z[0]) != 0)` directly, without `eval()`, you'd get the same answer `BoolRef: 1 & v__a != 0`.  Am I correct?  If so, then you need to look in the class BoolRef to fix how it implements `__repr__()`, to include some extra parenthesis in the final string.

Comment: You are right. I am getting `BoolRef: 1 & v__a != 0` when I am assigning it to a variable without eval()
Now I have to figure out how to deal with it. Thanks!!